# vue js serve problem - Module parse failed: Unexpected token (763:13)

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a new project like this:

[image]

There is a some mistake to create a project but i dont know what it means, anyway im opening the project and when i write "npm run serve" there is a problem like this:

[image]

```js
PS C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\vueApps\aos\aos-ch> npm run serve

> aos-ch@0.1.0 serve C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\vueApps\aos\aos-ch
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                              14:15:21
 error  in ./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (763:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process 
this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| }
| class RefImpl {
>     _rawValue;
|     _shallow;
|     _value;

 @ ./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js 1:0-233 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 2:0-216 16:4-17 40:4-17 107:13-18 108:32-37 115:16-21 1958:8-13 1962:13-23 1968:35-45 1970:16-21 1973:21-31 2071:19-25 2094:8-12 2135:8-13 2210:29-34 2557:27-30 2558:26-29 2559:28-31 2905:16-29 2912:16-29 3043:28-36 3362:41-56 3378:28-33 3463:8-15 3500:32-37 3647:27-32 3823:29-34 3951:12-25 3958:12-25 4568:17-22 4592:13-18 5173:26-32 5336:8-21 5340:8-21 5755:16-20 5761:12-16 6296:27-32 6328:12-19 6338:16-23 6356:93-100 6357:15-20 6767:60-75 6768:60-75 6769:60-75 6770:59-74 6847:16-21 6997:16-21 7150:21-28 7160:8-21 7161:134-149 7162:8-21 7210:30-39 7264:8-21 7266:8-21 7314:23-38 7334:46-55 7334:56-63 7389:14-24 7576:21-26 7586:21-31 7593:24-34 7596:21-31 7624:53-58 7630:52-57 7696:48-53
 @ ./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js
 @ ./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.2:8081&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

How to fix that problem, if you help me i will be glad. Thanks

Comment: Same issue here... Did you find the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your vue-cli, node and npm.

Comment: Please add in at the very least the command to  run the update

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. I did what @samuel said. Upgraded npm, upgraded yarn, ran "yarn upgrade", and the problem was gone! The upgrade changed @vue/compiler-sfc from version "^3.0.0" to "^3.1.0", and I suspect this was the real issue since it complained about an underscore it failed to parse.