# When I create a project using Vue 2, no problems occur, but when I create project using Vue 3, I can't run the server. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Tags: javascript, frontend, vuejs3

I installed Vue Js after that I created a project using Vue 2 the file is created and the server run's no problem.

After that I created a project using Vue 3 file is created but when I run the server using  `npm run serve`

I got error can anyone help me to solve this ?

I attached the image link of the error
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! It's best not to post images of either code or errors; see the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and this thread: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 for more info

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68235155/15393954, I think the issue is @vue/compiler-sfc. Make sure it is at "^3.1.0", or just run npm upgrade.